# NULL safe inequality comparisons in SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Currently, the only way I know how to express a NULL safe `!=` comparison in SQL Alchemy (where comparison with NULL entries evaluates as True, rather than NULL) is with:

```
or_(field == None, field != value)
```

Is there a way to express this in SQL Alchemy such that it will emit a MySQL `<=>` operation or a PostgreSQL `IS DISTINCT FROM` operation that treats NULL as just another possible value?

### Additional context

This came up as a bug in a utility that converts from an XML based query language to SQL Alchemy filter expressions: http://gerrit.beaker-project.org/#/c/2776/

The specific bug was in a snippet of code that looked like this:

```
query = getattr(field, op)(value)
```

Where "field" is the relevant SQL Alchemy model column, "op" is the relevant Python attribute name for the comparison operation, and "value" is the value to be checked against. For example, in the specific case of filtering for virtual machines running on a hypervisor with a particular name, it would be equivalent to doing:

```
query = Hypervisor.hypervisor.__eq__("KVM")
```

The bug arose not due to *value* potentially being `NULL` (that doesn't happen - the value is always a string), but when comparing against rows where the *column* contained a `NULL` value and the comparison operator was `__ne__`.

For every operator except `__ne__`, the standard SQL NULL handling works fine (the comparison returns NULL, which is interpreted as the row not matching the filter, which is what we want). However, for the case of `__ne__` we *do* want to return the rows that contain a NULL value in that column - we only want to exclude the ones where the value is set *and* it doesn't match the value we're comparing against.

So the code that originally looked like:

```
query = getattr(field, op)(value)
```

Now looks more like:

```
if op == "__ne__":
    query = or_(field == None, field != value)
else:
    query = getattr(field, op)(value)
```

That seems clumsy to me, so I'm asking if there is a method we can map "!=" to other than `__ne__` that would give us the alternate `NULL` handling at the database layer rather than emulating it with the SQL Alchemy equivalent of `field IS NOT NULL OR field != value` (as we have started doing now).

Comment: `IFNULL(field, '')` or similar to convert any nulls to an empty string?

Comment: there's different ways to go with this, you can implement an operator that spits out `<=>` / `IS DISTINCT FROM` or you can make an operator that spits out the `or_()` you have there.  But what none of them will do without making some concessions is to be able to handle the "None" as a bound value, that is, the expression needs to render differently if you feed in None vs. non-None (assuming bound values for non-None).  Which is not typically a problem (e.g. `x IS NOT NULL` vs. `x != %(value)s`) but if this is for like an executemany() type of thing, then it might be.

Comment: but I'm not really sure what you're going for.  The Core expression -> SQL mapping already makes an expression that's agnostic if you pass in "None" or a value (renders the operator based on the value), so it seems like maybe you're going for something that stays fixed on the SQL side.   I'd have to experiment with the DBAPI you're using to see what happens if you give it "None" as a bound value.

Comment: Added some more context on what we're doing - it's a data driven filter generator, and the specific problem is that we currently have to special case `__ne__` to get the right answer for rows with a `NULL` in the relevant column. If we can map that to a different database operator somehow, we may be able to remove the current special case and just change the operation -> method name mapping instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a few ways to plug an alternate operator in there, as well as creating a custom operator, but the most public/mainstream way to get at what happens when `__ne__()` is invoked is at the type level:

```
from sqlalchemy import TypeDecorator, type_coerce, String, or_

class NullComparisons(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String

    class comparator_factory(TypeDecorator.Comparator):
        def __ne__(self, other):
            expr = type_coerce(self.expr, String)
            return or_(expr == None, expr != other)
```

so that will do the OR thing:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(NullComparisons(50))
print(Thing.data != 'hi')
```

gives us:

```
thing.data IS NULL OR thing.data != :param_1
```

then for the PG/MySQL operator, what we really should have is the ability to link @compiles to operators directly.   But that hook isn't present right now, so with more effort than it ideally should require, we can make a custom column element to handle it:

```
from sqlalchemy import TypeDecorator, type_coerce, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import BinaryExpression
import operator
class IsDistinctFrom(BinaryExpression):
    pass

@compiles(IsDistinctFrom, "postgresql")
def pg_is_distinct_from(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "%s IS DISTINCT FROM %s" % (
                    compiler.process(element.left, **kw),
                    compiler.process(element.right, **kw),
                )

@compiles(IsDistinctFrom, "mysql")
def mysql_is_distinct_from(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "%s <=> %s" % (
                    compiler.process(element.left, **kw),
                    compiler.process(element.right, **kw),
                )

class AdvancedNullComparisons(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String

    class comparator_factory(TypeDecorator.Comparator):
        def __ne__(self, other):
            expr = type_coerce(self.expr, String)
            # this step coerces a literal into a SQL expression,
            # this can be done without the private API here but the private
            # function does the most thorough job, this could also be made
            # public
            other = self._check_literal(expr, operator.ne, other)
            return IsDistinctFrom(self.expr, other, operator.ne)
```

then we can try that out:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(AdvancedNullComparisons(50))

from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql, mysql
print(Thing.data != 'hi').compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect())
print(Thing.data != 'hi').compile(dialect=mysql.dialect())
```

gives us:

```
thing.data IS DISTINCT FROM %(param_1)s
thing.data <=> %s
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured SQL Alchemy was flexible enough that there was likely a way to do it at column definition time, but working out the details of actually doing it was beyond me :)

Comment: Just wanted to note that `<=>`  is actually the same as `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`. That is, it's an equality comparison not an inequality comparison, in spite of its similarity to `<>`.

Comment: And it looks like SQLAlchemy 1.1 added [.isnot_distinct_from()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.isnot_distinct_from) and [.is_distinct_from()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.is_distinct_from) for these, which is handy.

Comment: @DanC This should be the answer for this question. The only improvement that the second link is [.is_distinct_from](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.is_distinct_from)

Answer (score 0):

Use customize operator may help:
[sqlalchemy custom operator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.op)

eg:

> outerjoin(A,
>    B.outlet_id.op('<=>')(A.outlet_id))